# Best time to visit Goa

Tags: india, tours, guides, goa-india

Which is the best time to visit Goa. My company will be shut down on Christmas and New Year eve, and I'm planning to go to Goa during that time.

So is December-January right time to visit Goa?

Any info about stay, precautions, food, tourist spots, cost will be helpful.

Comment: Christmas and New Year isn't the best time to visit. You will pay n times the price, it will be crowded and will not be that pleasing.

Comment: I think, that after rewording this question to: isn't worth visiting Goa during Christmas season could make this question not off-topic and non-opinion based.